# Matlab: Covariance Matrix wrong result

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, covariance

I have to calculate Covaiance Matrix to do PCA, but whenever I compae my Covariance Matrix result with the covariance matrix resul from matlab (using Cov function), it gives different result.

So it means that my program is wrong.

Here is my Program:

```
InputMatrix=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 9 1 2];
Average=mean(InputMatrix);
[Rows,Columns]=size(InputMatrix);

DataNumbers=Rows*Columns;

%% Substraction
for loop_row=1:Rows
    for loop_column=1:Columns
        Substract_Matrix(loop_row,loop_column)=InputMatrix(loop_row,loop_column)-Average(loop_column);
    end
 end

 %% Transpose
 for loop1=1:Rows
     for loop2=1:Columns
         Transpose_Matrix(loop2,loop1)=Substract_Matrix(loop1,loop2);
     end
 end


%% Multiply
CovarianceMatrix=(Substract_Matrix*Transpose_Matrix)*1/DataNumbers;
```

The Covariance Matrix Output given by my program :

```
1.5926   -0.0741   -1.5185
-0.0741    1.2593   -1.1852
-1.5185   -1.1852    2.7037
```

Covariance Matrix Result given by Matlab Cov Function

```
16.3333   -3.1667   -3.1667
-3.1667    4.3333    4.3333
-3.1667    4.3333    4.3333
```

Can someone help me to solve this, 
I already asked about it, bu no one answered yet.. [T_T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741963/covariance-matrix-different-result-with-matlab)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Covariance Matrix Different Result with Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741963/covariance-matrix-different-result-with-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are making things complicated

try this

```
InputMatrix=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 9 1 2];
ave_matrix  = repmat(mean(InputMatrix),3,1)
(InputMatrix-ave_matrix)'*(InputMatrix-ave_matrix) / 2 % sample_num -1 which is 3-1
```

I see where you are going wrong , the DataNumbers is not Rows* columns
and the denominator should be DataNumbers -1

```
InputMatrix=[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 9 1 2];
Average=mean(InputMatrix);
[Rows,Columns]=size(InputMatrix);

DataNumbers=Columns;

%% Substraction
for loop_row=1:Rows
    for loop_column=1:Columns
        Substract_Matrix(loop_row,loop_column)=InputMatrix(loop_row,loop_column)-Average(loop_column);
    end
 end

 %% Transpose
 for loop1=1:Rows
     for loop2=1:Columns
         Transpose_Matrix(loop2,loop1)=Substract_Matrix(loop1,loop2);
     end
 end


%% Multiply
CovarianceMatrix=(Transpose_Matrix*Substract_Matrix)/(DataNumbers-1);
```

Comment: Do u know how to plot the InputMatrix with the Mean in the same figure..


%figure(2)
%imshow(ImSeq(:,:,1),[])
hold on
plot(InputMatrix, '.r')
plot(Average, '.g')
 hold off

But there are many points in the figure, while I just need to plot 3 points of Input and 1 Point of mean